# Laravel Show Categories Count not display

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an Sidebar menu in Laravel 5.5 and  i want show the categorie count with more IDs but they dont display any results.

My Code:

```
<?php
$count = DB::select('select category_id from products where category_id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
?>
```

and how can i choose more ID´s? example  `where category_id = 1 and 2`

i try it now over an week and i hope someone can help me here now.

My php code works but its not laravel;)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT category_id FROM products WHERE category_id = 2";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: r u using laravel controller,routes?

Comment: yes i use controller,routes

Comment: u need to write this code in laravel?

Comment: i have write it in laravel? the php code is just an example

Comment: ur laravel code plz?

Comment: how u pass ur id value?for where condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `DB::select()` returns an array of results, so you could count the results:

```
$count = count(DB::select('select category_id from products where category_id = :id', ['id' => 1]));
```

However, you might prefer to use the [query builder and the `count()` aggregate function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates):

```
$count = DB::table('products')->whereIn('category_id', [1])->count();
```

This allows you to pass multiple category_ids like so:

```
$count = DB::table('products')->whereIn('category_id', [1, 2, 3])->count();
```

Comment: Thanks but also no results,nothing display on page... i dont know,i have try now many things and nothing work.

Comment: did you display the count with `echo $count;`?

Comment: i am an idiot, no forget xD You are my Hero! Many Thanks it works fine:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **:**

```
<?php

$count = DB::select('select category_id from products where category_id = :id', ['id' => 1])[0]['category_id '];
echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: It comes this error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: you could show me function 'select' in class DB.php